# SQL Server Linked server and DTSX

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, linked-server

The architecture we are using is the following:

a.- 2 SQL Server servers.

b.- 1 SQL servers where is the integration server catalog (dtsx) and Jobs.

I need to execute from the SQL servers a stored procedure that executes one of the DTSX that is in the other server, I can perform this action by linked server.

But:
1.- If I execute via linked server in which server the execution is carried out? Will the performance of my SQL servers decrease?
2.- Is there another way to run dtsx and jobs that is not linked server?

Comment: What's a "BD server"?

Comment: SQL Server Database

Comment: You'll need to provide more info on this mysterious stored procedure that you are calling.